# directory path as user input, but for multiple folders at once

Tags: python

(Using Python 3.4)
So I have a big folder with 1500 folders in it. I want to analyze data that is 2 layers inside each folder. Each folder's name has the format:

`YYMMDD_XXXXX_####X` where `X` is a letter and `#` is a number. All I really care about is the `####X` part which is unique. Inside this folder is a folder called `"infosite-####X"` (the same `####X` as the parent folder), and inside this folder is an `rst` file called `"YYMMDD_XXXXX_####X_infosite.rst"` (also same ID) which has the data I want.

I've built the code for data analysis but I don't want to type out the whole directory when each directory has that unique 5mer sequence.

Right now I have the directory with a single file I want hard coded and do it like this:

```
import os
os.chdir("Z:/RunLog/160428_HV2VY_1892L/infosite-1892L")

user_input = input("Enter name of file: ")
assert os.path.exists(user_input + ".rst"), "I did not find the file at, " +        str(user_input)
f = open(user_input + ".rst" ,'r+')
print("Hooray we found your file!")
```

ideally I'd like to have something like

```
os.chdir("Z:/RunLog/*" + user_input + "/*" user_input + "/*" user_input + ".rst")
```

but this isn't really allowed, and I don't see how to use `glob.glob` with it.

Comment: You mean, the user input is that unique ID?

Comment: yep input is the unique ID

Comment: Is it important that your program invoke `os.chdir()`? Are you just doing that to set up the `open()`? If so, you could pass the absolute path to `open()` and avoid the `chdir()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the expression you've created to `glob()`, and use the result, like so:

```
import glob
import os

user_input = input("ID of file: ")
for filename in glob.glob(
    "Z:/RunLog/*" + user_input + "/*" user_input + "/*" user_input + "_infosite.rst"):
    f = open(filename)
    ...
```

Or, if you are not prepared to deal with multiple matching files:

```
user_input = input("ID of file: ")
filenames = glob.glob(
    "Z:/RunLog/*" + user_input + "/*" user_input + "/*" user_input + "_infosite.rst")
filename = filenames[0]
f = open(filename)
```

---

Also note that the creation of the glob pattern might be more readable like so:

```
pattern = 'Z:/RunLog/*{0}/*{0}/*{0}_infosite.rst'.format(user_input)
filenames = glob.glob(pattern)
```

Comment: It's more readable and pythonic to use  `str.format()` method.

Comment: Yes, it is. I originally posted a `str.format()` solution, but chose to extend OP's solution instead. I'll add `str.format()` in a moment.